# Validation/invariants enforcing in a CQRS app

Tags: php, domain-driven-design, cqrs, eventual-consistency

I've scoured SO and other forums/mailing lists in the search for answers on this topic, and while I know that the answer largely depends on the domain itself, and what is acceptable from an eventual consistency point of view, I still struggle to find a good solution.

The issue has to do with where to validate the business rules proper to the domain.

My domain is an online market place. A member (with the role Seller) can post an Ad to sell an item. The Seller can specify a minimum and a maximum number of items that can be purchased in a single order, and the price of the item.

A Buyer can buy an item off of a specific ad. The following rules have to be observed:

- They can specify the number of items that they would like to buy, which has to be between min and max allowed by the ad.
- They need to be active (as members can be banned).
- The ad needs to be active (Ads can be suspended).

My Market BC is the one that deals with ads and buy transactions. I designed it in the following way:

- Ad Aggregate root
- Member AR
- BuyTransaction AR

I'm struggling with how and where to validate the above business rules, which in this case span multiple aggregates. I would Ideally have a method:

```
$buyer->buy($adId, $quantity);
```

That would be called by a BuyItems command

```
$buyCommand = new BuyItems($adId, $qty);
```

On the Member aggregate.

Of the options I gather that I have:

1. Validate outside of the domain, in an outer layer - this means that I would validate the command before sending it into the domain. This would imply some logic leaking outside of the domain, but I would fetch the ad from a read model, validate the constraint (between min and max, ad active, user active), and then send the command.
   I would also do domain side validation in that case, in the form of a process manager that would issue a compensating action, or at least warn if an inconsistency occurs.
2. Define a service interface in the domain, and implement a service that gets the data from the read model, then validate in the command handler by calling the service. If data is invalid, then throw an exception. 
   Domain validation would have to occur here as well, because the read model might not be consistent (again using a process manager).
3. Load up the Ad and Member aggregate roots in the BuyItem handler, and pass it to the $buyer->buy($ad, $member, $qty); then in the buy() method in the AR, check that qty is between min and max. Don't really feel comfortable with this option, as I feed that I'm trying to cram transactional consistency, when I don't really need it (while I need to minimize the risks of commands with out of bound qty, or inactive member, it's not a huge deal if it happens and I issue a corrective action afterwards so I'm perfectly ok with eventual consistency).

Can anyone point me to what the best option is given that scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a business process that spans multiple Aggregates, that's for sure. For this you have two options:

1. Modify the Aggregates boundary by merging multiple Aggregate types into a single one. The code is simpler, the compensations are done by the database automatically by rollbacks. The scalability is not so great.
2. Use a Saga to model the entire process. You need to send compensating commands for each failure. This is the option that I will write about in the rest of the answer.

You basically have to choose between a single big (global) transaction and multiple smaller (local) transactions.

The Saga should contain only coordination logic, it should not enforce the business rules on its own. A hint on how to model it is this: when you add a new business rule regarding the Ad Buying Process, the Saga should not be modified.

The business rules (the invariants) should be checked by each Aggregate that owns the data needed for the validation. For example:

Rule 1: They can specify the number of items that they would like to buy, which has to be between min and max allowed by the ad - The Ad Aggregate

Rule 2: They need to be active (as members can be banned - The Buyer Aggregate

Rule 3: The ad needs to be active (Ads can be suspended) - The Ad Aggregate

Rule 1 and 3 are checked by the `Ad::buyedBy($buyerId, $quantity)` and Rule 2 is checked by the `Buyer::buyAd($buyerId, $quantity)`. The Saga would just glue those method calls. How does it do that it depends on you low level architecture and resilience requirements.

Supposing that you would use the style promoted by [cqrs.nu](http://cqrs.nu) where the Aggregates process Commands (they have methods like `handleXXX(XXX $command)`), like [I would have done](https://github.com/xprt64/dudulina), then your Aggregates and your Saga would look like this:

```
class Ad
{
    function handleBuyAd(BuyAd $command)
    {
        if (!$this->active) {
            throw new \Exception("Ad not active");
        }
        if ($command->quantity < $this->minimum || $command->quantity > $this->maximum) {
            throw new \Exception("Too litle or too many");
        }

        yield new AdWasBuyed($this->id, $command->buyerId, $command->quantity);
    }

    function handleCancelAdBuy(CancelAdBuy $command)
    {
        yield new AdBuyinWasCancelled($this->id, $command->buyerId, $command->quantity);
    }
}

class Buyer
{
    function handleBuyerBuysAd(BuyerBuysAd $command)
    {
        if ($this->banned) {
            throw new \Exception("Buyer is banned");
        }

        yield new BuyerBuyedAd($command->transactionId, $this->id, $command->buyerId, $command->quantity);
    }
}

class BuyAdSaga
{
    /** @var CommandDispather  */
    private $commandDispatcher; //injected

    function start($transactionId, $adId, $buyerId, $quantity)
    {
        $this->commandDispatcher->dispatchCommand(new BuyAd($transactionId, $adId, $buyerId, $quantity));
    }

    function processAdWasBuyed(AdWasBuyed $event) //"process" means only once
    {
        try {
            $this->commandDispatcher->dispatchCommand(new BuyerBuysAd($event->transactionId, $event->adId, $event->buyerId, $event->quantity));
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            // this is a compensating command
            $this->commandDispatcher->dispatchCommand(new CancelAdBuy($event->transactionId, $event->adId, $event->buyerId, $event->quantity));
        }
    }
}
```

The commands contain a `$transationId` used to identity the process of buying an Ad. It can be also seen as a type of correlation Id. You may dump it.

The Saga is started by the `start` method. You can also dump it and consider the Saga started by sending the first command to the Ad Aggregate. I've made it like this to be more explicit how this process starts.

If the `BuyAd` command fails then no compensation is needed but if the `BuyerBuysAd` command fails then a compensation is done by sending the command `CancelAdBuy` to the Ad Aggregate.

Note that this Saga only reacts to events by sending commands and nothing more. It does not enforce any business invariants, it just coordinates the entire process.

Comment: "The scalability is not so great.": That's why I avoided that solution thus far. However, Udi Dahan promoted a technique that might also be a possibility in this case here: http://udidahan.com/2008/02/29/how-to-create-fully-encapsulated-domain-models/. In a BuyTransaction::Initiate($ad, $buyer, $seller); method for instance, why not pass in the Ad AR, and validate the limits there? At the end of the day it's the BuyTransaction's job (in a paper business it would be anyway) to validate that the Trade matches the limits... This way the validation can occur rather early. am i missing something?

Comment: @KonelSum Aggregates should not depend on data they don't own. Also, in CQRS one does not query the write model, by definition.

Comment: @KonelSum If you follow these two rules then you will check the invariants in the right Aggregate. Otherwise you will go towards an anemic domain model by having something like this `BuyTransaction::Initiate($ad, $buyer, $seller)` that steals logic from the two Aggregates.

Comment: @KonelSum by doing that you would trade off concurrent access capacity for convenience/cohesion. All along the BuyTransaction, the `Ad` AR would be locked up for other transactions to access. Which might be a perfectly valid option if there's not much contention for `Ad`, but can cause locking problems in a transaction intensive context.

Comment: @constantin "process" means only once, did you add this in case we replay?

Comment: @KonelSum exactly.

Answer (score 1):

The domain model is the authority for its own current state, not any other parts of the process.

There are typically two different validations.  The first is the validation of the message; it your case, the buy message.  Does it have all of the required data, is the data in the correct shape, and so on.  This validation step is looking at the message *in isolation*, much in the way that you would validate an XML document.

Assuming that this is a command message, we now pass it to the domain model to act upon.  The domain model owns the business logic of *how the model will change in reaction to the message*.

So domain model knows whether the ad is active, whether this particular member is in good standing, whether the number of items is reasonable.  Thus, it gets to decide how it will change.  Maybe it won't change at all - implicitly discarding the message.  Maybe it will change by adding the message to an explicit list of discarded messages.

> I'm struggling with how and where to validate the above business rules, which in this case span multiple aggregates.

Sometimes, that's a hint that your aggregates boundaries aren't quite right; in others, it means you aren't thinking about reads correctly.

Typically, the message gets routed to the aggregate that is going to (maybe) change, and the capability to access the other model data needed to process the message is passed to the aggregate as arguments.

Comment: Thanks, that's insightful. "Typically, the message gets routed to the aggregate that is going to (maybe) change": In this case, an aggregate is created in my mind at least - $buyer->buy($ad, $qty) would/should result in a new Buy AR getting created. "and the capability to access the other model data needed to process the message is passed to the aggregate as arguments." Would options 2 and 3 that I outlined fall within this option? And "Sometimes, that's a hint that your aggregates boundaries aren't quite right" Thought about that as well - hints on how I could think about it differently?

Answer (score 0):

> They can specify the number of items that they would like to buy,
> which has to be between min and max allowed by the ad.
>
> They need to be active (as members can be banned).
>
> The ad needs to be active (Ads can be suspended).

It looks like #1 and #3 can be solved by making `Ad` spawn the new `BuyTransaction`, somewhat similarly as [here](http://udidahan.com/2009/06/29/dont-create-aggregate-roots/).

For #2, I've never seen systems enforce user validity via immediate consistency at the domain level (i.e. checking that current user is active in the same transaction as the one involving the `Ad` aggregate root). I would delegate that to the Access Control layer.

Comment: Fair point re #2 - I tried to simplify a bit for the question. The system must be granular enough however to allow for instance restricting member transactions completely, or below an arbitrarily defined level (i.e. no transactions over 10,000$).   At the AC level, it could just be determined wether a user can log in or not.

Comment: Does restriction enforcement need to be immediately consistent with the domain operation or can it tolerate a bit of delay/staleness?

Comment: It can tolerate some delay in most cases.

Comment: Then you have the option of checking restrictions outside the main transaction, or with a saga as Constantin explained.